# codeigniter class error

Tags: php, codeigniter

For some reason i cant get my model to work.. never had this problem before.

```
function overview($userid)
{

    // Load needed model
    $this->load->model('budget_model');
    $data['month_budget'] = $this->budget_model->get_monthly_budget($userid);

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
        {

            if(is_numeric($key))
            {
                $this->buget_model->update_buget($key,$value);
                echo "DONE";
            }

        }       

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    $data['main'] = 'super_admin/budget_edit_overview_view';
    $this->load->view('default/main_view',$data);

}
```

The model works fine with "$this->budget_model->get_monthly_budget($userid);" but i keep getting thir error,

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Admin::$buget_model
>
> Filename: controllers/admin.php
>
> Line Number: 166
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function update_buget() on a non-object
>   in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/therace/application/controllers/admin.php
>   on line 166

The model method,

```
function update_buget($id,$budget)
{

    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    // Update the month budget
    $data = array(
        'month_goal' => $budget
    );

    $this->db->update('budget_month', $data);

    return true;

}
```

Comment: Class name should start with Uppercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a typing error in line 166.

It is `$this->budget_model->update_buget($key,$value);`

not `$this->buget_model->update_buget($key,$value);`

Answer (score 2):

Read the error message carefully:

`Message: Undefined property: Admin::$buget_model`

Did you make a typo and actually mean `$budget_model`?

edit: There seems to be a lot of `budget` vs. `buget` in your code. I suggest a spellchecker.

Comment: Agreed, I see `$this->budget_model->` and `$this->buget_model->` in the controller function

Comment: I suggest proper IDE. spelling error doesn't matter much in programming as long as those spelling error are CONSISTANT.